# The permissions in the settings don't match the ones in the login-dialogue

Tags: authentication, permissions, facebook-login

For my App, I need a users birthdate and email-address. So I set up the permissions to that!
[image: permission settings]

In the preview it works just fine:

[image: login preview]

but in the actual login dialogue it does not!

[image: actual login]

Therefore, I don't have the permission. What do I do now?

Code: It's basically right out of facebook's getting started...

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 

  FB.init({ // init the FB JS SDK
    appId      : 'XXXXXXXX', // App ID from the App Dashboard
    channelUrl : 'http://nerdjokes.funpic.de/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain         communication
    status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
    cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      loggedIn();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      login(); //user hast not authorized the app. Display the dialogue
    } else {
      login();
    }
  });
};
  function login() {
   FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // connected
    } else {
        // cancelled
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you post some code. The question is a bit vague and ambiguous.

Comment: @War10ck well, there isn't much code, but I'll edit it, hold on